# What's the use of "standard input mode" for `git commit -F -` in Git Bash for Windows?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-commit

I understand that the following command takes the text from standard input and uses it as the message for the commit log:

```
echo "hello world" | git commit -F -
```

But, if you just have it as `git commit -F -` then it brings you to what I call "standard input mode" where Git Bash displays the message `(reading log message from standard input)` and awaits some kind of input...  I guess.  My question is what is this mode really and can it be used at all?  I've entered text and exited by using `ctrl-z` and `ctrl-c`, but had no luck in having the commit to run successfully afterwards.  It would just bring me back to the prompt.

Question: What is actually going on in "standard input mode" and can it be used to enter the commit log message successfully?

EDIT: I've tried `ctrl-d`, but nothing changes.  I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> When you use - in commands it tells the application to read from STDIN. Git notices that STDIN is empty (unless you echo and pipe first) so it starts listening for input. Once you type your message you have to tell it that you're finished by sending the EOF message.
>
> When you run echo hello | git commit -F - you're piping text into git so it uses the piped message.
>
> ~ [blockloop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903025/blockloop)

In order to use `git commit -F -` on Windows in the Git Bash console, you must append the command to `winpty` as so:

**`winpty git commit -F -`**

Afterwards, you will be taken to "standard input mode" as expected.  Instead of using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> as you would with Linux and Mac, **press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on a new line**.  This will indicate an EOF and save the commit log message.

If you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> on the same line as the message, then `^Z` will be entered as text next to the message and nothing else will happen. You need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on a separate and empty line.

So, to edit blockloop's example:

```
winpty git commit -F -
my message blah blah<enter>
<CTRL-Z><enter>
```

Source: [Github](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/867)

Comment: No problem!  If something in the explanation doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Use CTRL-D (EOF) after you enter your message. CTRL-C terminates, CTRL-Z pauses. EOF tells STDIN that your message is complete.

```
git commit -F -
my message blah blah<enter>
<CTRL-D>
```

When you use `-` in commands it tells the application to read from STDIN. Git notices that STDIN is empty (unless you echo and pipe first) so it starts listening for input. Once you type your message you have to tell it that you're finished by sending the `EOF` message. The key combination for `EOF` is CTRL-D

When you run `echo hello | git commit -F -` you're piping text into git so it uses the piped message.

Out of curiousity, why not use `git commit -m 'your message here'`?

Comment: I tried, but no luck.  Nothing changes.  But, thanks for elaborating!  Argh...  I also tried "\0", "\n", and "\eof"

Comment: Once you've typed your message you press enter for a new line then push CTRL-D

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10.  And, yes, I did type in your example letter by letter.

Comment: If you're using git bash as your question says then CTRL-D is EOF, but if you're using Powershell/CMD then CTRL-Z is EOF. Try the process I outlined above with CTRL-Z on a new line and see if it works.

Comment: Okay, so I tried CTRL-Z once more, and I just get a message saying "Stopped" and then it brings me back to the prompt.  The commit did not go through.  I know... it's strange.

I'm pretty sure I'm using Git Bash.  It says MINGW64 at the top

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122353/discussion-between-blockloop-and-dash).

Answer (score 0):

You can try SHIFT+esc , and after insert q and press Enter .

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work either.  I'm really curious as to what the Git people have to say about it.